# Can I parallel unbiased photo-diodes for op-amp I-to-V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

Can I use several photo-diodes (unbiased mode), with different light sources for each, in parallel with a current to voltage op-amp circuit? I don't recall seeing it done that way but it seems to me that the currents should simply sum.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD7zIh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Looks reasonable. You'll get some shunting from the other sources which you can probably establish by estimating their impedances (high). Thinks about different levels of excitation ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this but watch the overall shunt capacitance of all the photodiodes and wiring (if any) - you'll need a small capacitor across R1 to balance this. The small capacitor is there to counter the capacitance of all the PDs.